# how to pull google drive file id's from list python?

Tags: python, list, google-api, google-drive-api

Hello everyone I have multiple files in my google drive that I need to get the file id for to share download links to people. But I cant seem to get but 1 file id at a time. Is there a way to pull all the file ids and match them with a list?

In my list A,B C

each letter represents an order number I was trying to keep it simple but A would actually be an order number 3472834, B= 3293881, C =,3498249.

In google drive example: File1,File2,File3

The files that are in my google drive are pdf printouts of the orders. They are actually named the order numbers File 1= 3472834, File 2= 3293881, File 3 =3498249

So my goal is to iterate over the ListIDS each one and get the corresponding Google file id. But I cant seem to get it to do but the first google file id each time.

Code:

```
ListIDS= ['A','B','C']
for eachId in ListIDS:

service = create_service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
filename= f'{ListID}'
query = "name contains " + "'"+ filename +"' and trashed = false"
response = service.files().list(q=query, fields= 'files(id,name)').execute()
files = response.get('files')
if files:
  print("File Found!")
  google_file_name=  files[0].get('name')
  google_file_id = files[0].get('id')
  print (google_file_id)
  print(google_file_name)
else:
  print("FileNot Found")

FileURL= "https://drive.google.com/file/d/"+ google_file_id + "/view?usp=sharing"
```

But again the problem is I only get the 2nd value B for all 3 lists id's printed out for example

```
output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/FileB_ID_Path/view?usp=sharing
```

But my expected outcome would be:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FileA_ID_Path/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FileB_ID_Path/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FileC_ID_Path/view?usp=sharing
```

Any help please.

Comment: In your script, what is `ListIDS= ['A','B','C']`, `for eachId in ListIDS:` and `filename`? In your script, it seems that those are not used. And also, I cannot understand `In google drive example: File1,File2,File3 In my list A,B C I need to match up the File1 with A, File2 with B, and File3 with C`. I thought that if `ListIDS= ['A','B','C']` is the file IDs, you can directly created the URL like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing` using the file ID. So, I cannot understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: I guess `A`, `B`, `C` correspond to strings present in certain of your file names. If that's the case, I guess only `B` actually is included in a file title, since that's the only URL you are getting. Also, when you mention `output`, what exactly do you mean? Are you printing `FileURL`? Or returning it? Finally, first you use `Filename`, with capital `F`, and then `filename`. I guess this is a typo and both refer to the same variable?

Comment: @Tanaike Ive updated the content to explain a little more. The ListIDS are actually the name of the file in google drive that I want to match and find the google file id.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the filenames like `ListIDS= ['A','B','C']`. The files of those filenames are put in your Google Drive.
- You want to retrieve the file IDs of the files using the filenames.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, using `ListIDS= ['A','B','C']`, one search query is used.

```py
ListIDS = ['A','B','C']  # filenames

service = create_service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
qFiles = ["name contains " + "'" + e + "'" for e in ListIDS]
query = "(" + " or ".join(qFiles) + ") and trashed = false"
response = service.files().list(q=query, fields='files(id,name)').execute()
files = response.get('files')
values = {}
for e in files:
    for f in ListIDS:
        if f in e.get('name'):
            id = e.get('id')
            v = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + id + "/view?usp=sharing"
            if values.get(f):
                values[f].append(v)
            else:
                values[f] = [v]
print(values)
```

- When this script is run, the following JSON object is returned.

  ```
    {
      'A': ["https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing"],
      'B': ["https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing"],
      'C': ["https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing", "https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=sharing"]
    }
  ```
- From your showing script, `name contains '###'` is used as the search query. So, when there are multiple files are returned by one filename, those file IDs are put in the array.

#### Pattern 2:

If `ListIDS` is large, the above pattern might not be able to be used. So, when pattern 1 cannot be used, please use this pattern 2. In this pattern, using `ListIDS= ['A','B','C']`, the multiple search queries are used.

```py
ListIDS = ['A','B','C']  # filenames

service = create_service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
files = []
for filename in ListIDS:
    query = "name contains " + "'" + filename + "' and trashed = false"
    response = service.files().list(q=query, fields='files(id,name)').execute()
    files.extend(response.get('files'))
values = {}
for e in files:
    for f in ListIDS:
        if f in e.get('name'):
            id = e.get('id')
            v = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + id + "/view?usp=sharing"
            if values.get(f):
                values[f].append(v)
            else:
                values[f] = [v]
print(values)
```

- In this case, the same result as the above one is obtained.

Comment: pattern 1 worked perfectly thank you very much!

Comment: @seanofdead Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.